# Run jar file methods in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jar

I am trying to call jar file methods in my jsp, but it doesn't call the methods. I have put the jar file into `WEB_INF/lib` folder and build the path.
I also imported this propperly in my jsp.

Here my code for importing:

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.esign.genericlog.*" %>
```

Genericlog contains the class `GenericLog`, and in it the method which I am trying to call.

Here my code for calling the method:

```
<%
    GenericLog gl = new GenericLog();
    String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password"); 

    gl.write(uname);
    gl.write(pass);
    gl.writeInfo(uname);
%>
```

Comment: is it giving some error/calling write method of some other package?

Comment: It's giving a `QuestionMissingException`. Naveed, please include the question in the Question, along with as much as possible detail about the concrete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what error do you found when you compile or run?

I have a jsp file using a jar class like this:

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.logging.Log" %>
<%
Log log = Log();
log.debug("mi debug message");

%>

<html> ...
```

and that class (Log) is in a jar file.
Try to import the classes you have to instance.

Answer (score 0):

Put your property files inbuilt path. For clear view check this link, might help!
http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/log4j/sample-log4j-properties-file-configuration-1.html